# React library that uses flow causes issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package.json

I am relatively new to js & react so please bear with me! 
I started a new project using `create-react-app` and react `16.12.0`. I installed a [library](https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-resize-aware) which I guess uses [flow](https://flow.org/).
Trying to use this (`npm install`) library gives me the following SynatError:

```
./node_modules/react-resize-aware/src/useResizeAware.js
SyntaxError: [...]\node_modules\react-resize-aware\src\useResizeAware.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (5:31)

  3 | import ResizeListener from './ResizeListener';
  4 | 
> 5 | const defaultReporter = (target: ?HTMLElement) => ({
    |                                ^
  6 |   width: target != null ? target.offsetWidth : null,
  7 |   height: target != null ? target.offsetHeight : null,
  8 | });
```

I feel like this is an issue on my side or at least an issue I could fix by doing some changes to the project's `package.json`. 
If so, I would be happy if you could explain to me how.

//EDIT: 
I tried adding `flow` to my project as [described here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-flow/) but it gives me the same error.
What works is copying the source of the library into my project and importing it from this local version.
But I would really like to use the npm package, and not maintain a local version of the lib myself.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I simply imported from the wrong path. I used

```
import moduleName from "lib-name/src";
```

instead of

```
import moduleNamefrom "lib-name";
```